# How to enable & use workload monitoring on a GKE Autopilot mode cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

The [Autopilot overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) doc claims that a Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster in Autopilot mode supports Monitoring *Pre-configured: System monitoring* but *Optional: System and workload monitoring*.

I would like to use said workload monitoring on an Autopilot cluster, with a `apiVersion: monitoring.gke.io/v1alpha1` and `kind: PodMonitor` CRD, [as documented here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-metrics#workload-metrics).

However, [the UI says](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list/overview) *"Cloud Monitoring cannot be edited in Autopilot clusters."* and `gcloud container clusters update my-cluster --monitoring=WORKLOAD` says `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.update) Must include system monitoring if any monitoring is enabled.` but the same with `--monitoring=SYSTEM,WORKLOAD` says `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.`

How do you use workload monitoring in Autopilot clusters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick, for now, is to use not the Web Console UI but the CLI with `gcloud` **`beta`**,
[as documented here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-metrics#gcloud):
*"Note: GKE workload metrics is currently a Preview, so be sure to use the gcloud beta commands."*

Also note that *"GKE workload metrics requires GKE control plane version 1.20.8-gke.2100 or later"*,
[as documented here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-metrics#requirements).